# Problem installing googlecharts gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation

I am trying to use the googlecharts gem to create some quick charts.  Here are the rubyforge and github sites:

http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/
http://github.com/mattetti/googlecharts/tree/master

After installing, I keep getting an error saying "no such file to load -- googlecharts" even though when I do a "gem list", the gem is listed.  I have restarted my server.  Anyone know what could be going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/), you need to

```
require 'gchart'
```

but it sounds like you might be doing

```
require 'googlecharts'
```

instead.

Comment: ahh i can't believe i missed that.  maybe i need to catch up on some sleep

Comment: I have the same problem. I have tried require 'gchart' and 'googlecharts' but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

You must do a `gem install googlecharts` first and then add `gem "googlecharts"` to your gemfile, then run bundle install. You should be free from the error afterwards.